# Laravel 4.2 File Upload Class not detecting size for octet stream files

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-4

I am having a weird issue with Laravel 4.2 and I cannot find any resources with this question asked.

I have a simple file upload method in one of my controllers, if the file being uploaded is an image with the mime type "application/octet-stream" it is not able to detect the file size. However if the image is of the file type image/jpeg it can detect the file size.

This is the code.

```
        $filetype = Input::get('filetype');
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $destinationPath = public_path().sprintf("/uploads/");
        $filename = str_random(18);
        $extension =$file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
        $filesize = Input::file('file')->getSize();
        if(isset($file)) {
            echo "printing";
            echo $filesize;
        } else {
            echo "file not found";
        }
        var_dump($file);
```

There's nothing fancy here. Is there an extension that I need to install.

Comment: what is the result of dumping the file after the upload `dd(Input::file('file'))` ? cause at the end Laravel upload is just a wrapper to Symfony upload class

Comment: On dumping i see the symfony upload object with the file. But it is lacking some of the parameters like file type which is exactly what i need and i cannot figure out why it is lacking it.

Comment: try to update your libraries and make sure that your php installation is correct